# How to migrate from Laravel to express

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, express, backend

I have a live web app made in laravel. Is there a way for me to migrate the entire thing on express ? Or 
Can I have an environment where I use both laravel and express each specialising in the things that they do best?

Comment: Is this a test question? :D Its hard to automate upgrade from Laravel 5.x to 5.x+1 yet alone to different language / framework technology. How on earth did this question come to your mind is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to migrate the entire thing on express?

Generally to move form one technology to another, you will need to re-write the application in that technology. This is often not something that can be automated, as you'd be taking business rules from one platform and applying them to something in a totally different language / platform.

> Can I have an environment where I use both laravel and express each specialising in the things that they do best?

I think you're referring to a micro-service architecture. In this case you can indeed have multiple small applications which all carry out one job. You can then have them make calls to each other and work together. It's much like having multiple people on a team (one designer, one developer, one tester) who each do different things and can pass work between the team.